# How can I get bluetooth data of surrounding devices with pyscript on web (Client - Side)

Tags: python, web, bluetooth, client-side, pyscript

We are developing a web project in which we need to get the bluetooth data of the surrounding devices (ibeacons) with Python. Actually, we tried to do this on the client side with the google web bluetooth api, but we couldn't because the modules were not working. We want to receive the data we can get with the Python Bleak library on the client side and save it in the session. We think we can do this with the best pyscript. However, our problem is: "The Bleak Library does not work with the pyscript library".
How can I solve this problem? Could you please add the Bleak library among the libraries that can work integrated with pyscript?
Or does anyone have a different suggestion?
Where can I find the list of libraries that work integrated with Pyscript?

Comment: You will need to use the APIs that the browser provides. A browser runs an app in a security sandbox. Python libraries interface with the operating system which is not possible inside the browser. Google search for `HTML DOM Bluetooth.

Comment: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/

Comment: Thanks for your advices but we already tried "bluetooth api" but it isnt work. Unfortunately.

Comment: If the browser Bluetooth API does not work for you, then nothing will. That is the only API available inside the browser.